# Executable symbolic link results in "command not found"

Tags: symlink, ln

I created a symbolic link (yesterday) like this:

```
sudo ln -s bin/python /usr/bin/prj-python
```

When I run:

```
prj-python file.py
```

I get:

```
prj-python: command not found
```

When I try creating the link again, I get:

> ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/bin/prj-python': File exists

Why is that happening? My `$PATH` is:

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/real/RealPlayer

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You forgot the initial slash before `bin/python`. This means `/usr/bin/prj-python` now points to `/usr/bin/bin/python`. What would you like it to point to exactly?

Comment: There is not initial slash. the `pwd` is `/home/xralf/my_virtual_env` and it has subdirectory `bin` with `python` command

Comment: Than, you've forgot `$PWD/` before `bin`.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I used this command as it was in the book.

Answer (score 33):

Things to check:

- Perform an `ls -l /usr/bin/prj-python`

If it's like:
`lrwxrwxrwx (...) /usr/bin/prj-python -> bin/python` 
The file will actually be searched at **/usr/bin/bin/python** (that's what xralf tried to say). Fix:
`rm /usr/bin/prj-python`
`ln -s /full/path/to/your/python /usr/bin/python-prj`

- If your `bin/python` is a shell script (aka. wrapper-script) check the *#!-line* (sometimes called *shebang*-line) at the first line. If there's a typo like `#!/bin/bush` that will cause a *not found* error message also.

Comment: thank you, your answer is even more careful and educational. Sorry I already accepted.

Comment: this helped a lot...most of the answers if found were about $PATH

Comment: I use an ln without a parameter . People should use ln -s indeed, thus creating a symbolic link.

Comment: Helped, and I used `ln -s $PWD/python /usr/bin/python-prj`. `$PWD` is used for getting full path.